# Description list with enumitem

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

I would like to use `enumitem` package to create a description list so that the label has no indent, the item immediately follows the label, and the second line of the item has no indent. Is it this possible?

Comment: A similar effect can be obtained with `\paragraph{label} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`, but of course there the "meaning" of the command is different from `description`.

Answer (score 2):

With the option `leftmargin=0pt` you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
\item[label] \lipsum[4]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```